# SQL Query to limit results to yesterday and a specific 8 hour period

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have searched extensively through this site (and others) to try and narrow down the best way to accomplish a SQL query that will return a set of time stamped data results from yesterday within an 8 hour shift window. Couple of challenges are that this is being programmed in a proprietary (DG-LOGIK) data visualization tool that uses a JDBC connector to the SQL database so some of the standard datetime functions aren't recognized.

The query that I have successfully gotten to work is:

```
SELECT MAX(TimeOfSample) as TimeOfSample, SUM(SampleValue) as SampleValue FROM {trend_log} 
WHERE TimeOfSample >= GETDATE()-1 AND (DATEPART(HOUR,TimeOfSample)>=07 AND DATEPART(HOUR,TimeOfSample)<=15)
GROUP BY
DATEPART(YEAR, TimeOfSample),
DATEPART(MONTH, TimeOfSample),
DATEPART(DAY, TimeOfSample),
DATEPART(HOUR,TimeOfSample),
(DATEPART(MINUTE,TImeOfSample) / 15)
ORDER BY TimeOfSample
```

**Challenge:** If you are within today's time period of the shift both today and yesterday results return. I tried limiting `TimeOfSample = GETDATE()-1`, but I get an error return on the equal comparison. How can I limit this query to return only yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the `where` clause you want:

```
WHERE TimeOfSample >= CAST(GETDATE()-1 as date) AND
      TimeOfSample < CAST(GETDATE() as date) AND
      (DATEPART(HOUR,TimeOfSample) >= 07 AND DATEPART(HOUR, TimeOfSample) <= 15)
```

You need to specify the lower and upper bounds of yesterday.